# Twitter4J + Android: Authentication Challenge is Null Exception

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J library for OAuth authentication but I get "Authentication Challenge is Null Exception" even before It opens the Twitter login page.

Here is the code.

```
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    try
    {

        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Startup.TWITTER_KEY, Startup.TWITTER_SECRET);

        String callbackURL = "twitter-client:///";

        RequestToken rToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL);

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e)
    {
    // access token is already available, or consumer key/secret is not set.
        if(!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()){
            System.out.println("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Network Host not responding: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //This exception. 
    }
```

Exception:

> E/Home    ( 4393): Received
>   authentication challenge is null
>   E/Home    ( 4393): Received
>   authentication challenge is
>   nullRelevant discussions can be on the
>   Internet at: E/Home    ( 4393):
>     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6c607809
>   or E/Home    ( 4393):
>     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0f1d8134
>   E/Home    ( 4393):
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6c607809-0f1d8134
>   cab4c0ac-d492a113], statusCode=-1,
>   retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null,
>   version=2.2.2} E/Home    ( 4393):     at
>   twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:204)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:108)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:271)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   com.sharj.trafik.view.Home.askOAuth(Home.java:157)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   com.sharj.trafik.view.Home.access$0(Home.java:143)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   com.sharj.trafik.view.Home$3.onClick(Home.java:110)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) E/Home    ( 4393): Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Received
>   authentication challenge is null
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1153)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1095)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1048)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:121)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    at
>   twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:168)
>   E/Home    ( 4393):    ... 18 more

It contains following links, but Google doesn't have much on this.

http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6c607809

http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0f1d8134

Comment: Full stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: i'm having the same issue: did you ever get this solved? incorrect times didn't do it for me.

Comment: No I wasn't able to solove it so I dropped the integration for a while. Will try again soon.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to fix it???? My datetime and timezone are correct.

Comment: I faced this issue and problem was the time. My emulator time was not right

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that if the time stamp on the oAuth call is incorrect, the server returns a 401 status error which on Android devices causes the "Received authentication challenge is null" exception to be thrown.  All of the devices that were having this problem had incorrect times, and fixing the times fixed the problem.

Perhaps this is your issue as well?

Comment: Part of the oAuth protocol involves sending a time stamp with each command (this is probably handled by the class you are using).  There server compares the time stamp to it's current time, and if it does not fall within a certain window (for the server I am using it is 300 seconds), it will reject the command with a 401 error.  Unfortunately, Android does not handle the 401 error gracefully (this is a bug IMHO), and throws the exception that you are seeing.  If you set the time correctly, the problem goes away. (note that any other oAuth errors will also generate a 401 error).

Comment: This answer definitely needs more visibility!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902350/android-twitter-received-authentication-challenge-is-null

Comment: Still facing same issue, please help me

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. First I was getting it when doing `getOAuthRequestToken()`. My consumer key and consumer secret were coming from `.properties` file, and turned out they had a trailing space, so were seen as invalid by Twitter's API.

After that, I also was getting the same 401 when doing `getOAuthAccessToken()`. Here, I wasn't correctly persisting and re-constructing `RequestToken` object.

Comment: have you got solution of this problem ?
i have used twitter4j-media-support-4.0.4 jar file

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me when I called the following twice in a row:

```
 requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    return requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
```

Comment: I had the same issue... the TWICE was due to the User Cancelling OUT of the oAUTH the first time and then going back in a SECOND time to Authorize.  We were using the twitter.getSingleton "reusable" instance... across the calls... and that would NOT work.  We had to create the twitter instance each time using the ConfigurationBuilder

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:  I had this exception even after I fixed the date&time but when I looked in logcat at the params that twittherj sent to server the timestamp was still wrong - so I force-closed the app and after that exception was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I too stumbled across this problem. Check my solution in another thread [Android: Twitter4J Exception (Received Authentication Challenge Is Null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953819/android-twitter4j-exception-received-authentication-challenge-is-null/16186658#16186658)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and fixed it by Using Asynchronous task 
as I answered in the following link
[Android Twitter exception error :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165553/android-twitter-exception-error/17135009#17135009)