# Android Twitter Received authentication challenge is null

Tags: android, twitter

I am using Twitter android integration. I already successfully share text on twitter from android app. But now my code is not working.

I checked following demos :

1. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/
2. http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/

   No one worked successfully. I dont know why my code is not working now, which is working before.

**Following is my logcat warnings :**

```
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928): Received authentication challenge is nullRelevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dceba048
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-dceba048 b8c63e52-c088647f], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:200)
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:121)
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:276)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.loginToTwitter(MainActivity.java:270)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:257)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity$Asy.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:98)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity$Asy.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1153)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1095)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1048)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
01-03 04:17:13.909: W/System.err(8928):     ... 15 more
```

From Logcat

```
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928): Received authentication challenge is nullRelevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
01-03 04:17:13.899: W/System.err(8928):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dceba048
```

I checked both the link. I checked [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/374) but not getting success.

Can anybody face the same issue before ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but still confuse what is the reason why Twitter not worked. I solved it by running project in different device and It works. Strange!

If somebody facing problem in Twitter then you need also test in different devices.

Comment: How do you fix it. I am facing the similar problem.

Comment: I just test in different devices, and its works.

Comment: correct answer should be Ankur's...

Comment: Testing in different devices fixed the issue? Why and how? If I understood correctly you only check that your solution only work on some devices, not allways correct?